# Explicit formula for the recursive expression

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

In a Python program while trying to compute some expressions, I've encountered a recursive sequence $\{k_i\}$

for any $0 \le k_0 \le 1$ we have:
$$
k_i = 
\begin{cases}
k = k_0 \quad \text{if} \quad i = 0 \\ 
\dfrac{2\sqrt{k_{i-1}}}{1+k_{i-1}} \quad \text{for i > 0}
\end{cases}
$$

Is it possible to convert this recursive expression to an **explicit** formula where I could only give $i$ as input and get back $k_i$ as output

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I don’t think that there is an explicit formula but it seems that $k_i\to1$ very quickly

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Yes it converges quickly to 1

Comment: So why do you need an explicit formula if you can calculate $k_i$ manually for small $i$ and approximate it by $1$ for large $i$?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: For vectorization reason. The recursive formulas cannot be vectorized in Numpy. An explicit formula will yield results faster.

Comment: There should be no problem in vectorization because you can just define a function which applies your transformation $n$ times. You can even just store the first - say 10 - expressions „symbolically“ and then return $1$ whenever $i>10$

Comment: If you want I can post some code as an example once I am at home

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Yes, that will be nice!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102202/discussion-between-maximilian-janisch-and-thiziri-yoor).

Comment: This is related to tha AGM: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arithmetic-GeometricMean.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible and related to the AGM. You decide if it's okay.
 Let
$$ k_0 \!=\! k'(q) \!:=\!
 \left(\frac{\theta_4(0,q)}{\theta_3(0,q)}\right)^2 \!=\!
1 - 8q + 32q^2  + \dots \tag{1} $$
where $\,\theta_3(0,q)\,$ and $\,\theta_4(0,q)\,$ are Jacobi
theta functions and where $\,k'(q)\,$ is the generating function
of [OEIS sequence A139820](http://oeis.org/A139820).
Then it is known that
$$ k_n := k'(q^{2^n}) = \frac{2\sqrt{k_{n-1}}}{1+k_{n-1}}. \tag{2} $$
Using the inverse function of $\,k'\,$ 
let $\, q := k'^{(-1)}(k_0),\,$ equation $(2)$
is an explicit formula for $\,k_n.$

This is a numerical example. Let $\,q = .01\,$ and
$\,k_0 \approx 0.92310649897852255... = k'(q).\,$
Then $\,k_1 \approx 0.99920031990402559... = k'(q^2).\,$
Next $\,k_2 \approx 0.99999992000000319... = k'(q^4).\,$
Next $\,k_3 \approx 0.99999999999999920... = k'(q^8).\,$
In general $\,k_n = k'(q^{2^n}).\,$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't get it, could you please elaborate more? Thanks